# Popsql is showing me the error. What is right syntax of foriegn key?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
  emp_id INT,
  emp_name VARCHAR(20),
  emp_salary INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(emp_id)
);

CREATE TABLE branch(
  branch_id INT,
  branch_name VARCHAR(20),
  mgr_id INT,
  FORIEGN KEY(mgr_id) REFRENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: RTFM https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you only have two typos in the syntax:

FORIEGN = FOREIGN

REFRENCES = REFERENCES